# A known design pattern for dynamic factory

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory

Does this have a proper name?

```
public class SomethingFactory {
    private final String someParameter;

    public SomethingFactory(String someParameter) {
        this.someParameter = someParameter;
    }

    public Something create(String anotherParameter) {
        return new Something(someParameter, anotherParameter);
    }
}

public class Something {
    public final String someParameter;
    public final String anotherParameter;
    public Something(String someParameter, String anotherParameter) {
        this.someParameter = someParameter;
        this.anotherParameter = anotherParameter;
    }
}
```

What's different from a regular factory is that you have to specify a parameter at runtime to create() whenever you need to create an object.

That way you can make a singleton factory within Spring context for example, configuring first half of parameters there, and then finish with the rest of parameters at runtime when you call create().

**Why I need that in the first place if you're curious:**

I used to have regular singleton objects in Spring context and it was fine in thread-per-request applications, but now my whole app is non-blocking and I can't use ThreadLocal to keep stuff throughout entire request processing. For example, to keep info on timings with something like Apache StopWatch.

I needed to find a way to implement a "request scope" in a multithreading, non-blocking environment without having to supply the object representing the scope in every method (that would be silly) of my code.

So I thought let's make every (service) class take this scope object in constructor and let's create those classes on every request, but that goes against the singletons. The singletons we're talking are like, UserService that logs a user in, or a CryptoService that generates digital signatures. They're configured once in Spring, injected wheneven needed and everything's ok. But now I need to create those service classes in every method where they're needed, instead of just referencing an injected singleton instance.

So I thought let's call those singletons "templates" and whenever you need an actual instance you call create() supplying the said scope object. That way every class has the scope object, you just have to keep supplying it into other template service constructors. The full thing would look like this:

```
public class UserService {
    private final Scope scope;
    private final Template t;
    private UserService(Template t, Scope scope) {
        this.t = t;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public void login(String username) {
        scope.timings.probe("before calling database");
        t.database.doSomething(username);
        scope.timings.probe("after calling database");
    }

    public static class Template { /* The singleton configured in Spring */
        private Database database;
        public void setDatabase(Database database) { /* Injected by Spring */
            this.database = database;
        }

        public UserService create(Scope scope) {
            return new UserService(this, scope);
        }
    }
}

public class LoginHttpHandler { /* Also a Spring singleton */
    private UserService.Template userServiceT;

    public void setUserServiceT(UserService.Template userServiceT) { /* Injected by Spring */
        this.userServiceT = userServiceT;
    }

    public void handle(HttpContext context) { /* Called on every http request */
        userServiceT.create(context.scope).login("billgates");
    }
}
```

In Spring you'd just describe a UserService.Template bean with the appropriate dependencies it needs and then inject that bean whenever a UserService is needed.

I just call that a "template". But like always I feel it's already been done. Does it have any name?

Comment: The builder pattern? http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html (not the GOF builder pattern)

Answer (score 0):

That is almost the example given for Guice's [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject):

```
public class RealPaymentFactory implements PaymentFactory {
  private final Provider<CreditService> creditServiceProvider;
  private final Provider<AuthService> authServiceProvider;

  @Inject
  public RealPaymentFactory(Provider<CreditService> creditServiceProvider, Provider<AuthService> authServiceProvider) {
    this.creditServiceProvider = creditServiceProvider;
    this.authServiceProvider = authServiceProvider;
  }

  public Payment create(Date startDate, Money amount) {
    return new RealPayment(creditServiceProvider.get(), authServiceProvider.get(), startDate, amount);
  }
}

public class RealPayment implements Payment {
  public RealPayment(
    CreditService creditService,  // from the Injector
    AuthService authService,  // from the Injector
    Date startDate, // from the instance's creator
    Money amount) // from the instance's creator
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Assisted injection is used to "create classes that need extra arguments at construction time".

Also, this is similar to [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), so you could have a `PartialUserService` that creates a `UserService`.